# Apply an affine transform to a bounding rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a pedestrian tracking algorithm using Python3 & OpenCV.

We can use SIFT keypoints as an identifier of a pedestrian silhouette on a frame and then perform brute force matching between two sets of SIFT keypoints (i.e. between one frame and the next one) to find the pedestrian in the next frame.
To visualize this on the sequence of frames, we can draw a bounding rectangle delimiting the pedestrian. This is what it looks like :

[image: tracking example]

The main problem is about characterizing the motion of the pedestrian using the keypoints. The idea here is to find an affine transform (that is translation in x & y, rotation & scaling) using the coordinates of the keypoints on 2 successives frames. Ideally, this affine transform somehow corresponds to the motion of the pedestrian. To track this pedestrian, we would then just have to apply the same affine transform on the bounding rectangle coordinates.
That last part doesn’t work well. The rectangle consistently shrinks over several frames to inevitably disappear or drifts away from the pedestrian, as you see below or on the previous image :

[image: tracking results]

To specify, we characterize the bounding rectangle with 2 extreme points :

[image: bounding rectangle coordinates]

There are some built-in cv2 functions that can apply an affine transform to an image, like cv2.warpAffine(), but I want to apply it only to the bounding rectangle coordinates (i.e 2 points or 1 point + width & height).

To find the affine transform between the 2 sets of keypoints, I’ve written my own function (I can post the code if it helps), but I’ve observed similar results when using cv2.getAffineTransform() for instance.

Do you know how to properly apply an affine transform to this bounding rectangle ?

---

**EDIT** : here’s some explanation & code for better context :

- The pedestrian detection is done with the pre-trained SVM classifier available in openCV : `hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())` & `hog.detectMultiScale()`
- Once a first pedestrian is detected, the SVM returns the coordinates of the associated bounding rectangle `(xA, yA, w, h)` (we stop using the SVM after the 1st detection as it is quite slow, and we are focusing on one pedestrian for now)
- We select the corresponding region of the current frame, with `image[yA: yA+h, xA: xA+w]` and search for SURF keypoints within with `surf.detectAndCompute()`
- This returns the [keypoints](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html) & their associated descriptors (an array of 64 characteristics for each keypoint)
- We perform brute force matching, based on the L2-norm between the descriptors and the distance in pixels between the keypoints to construct pairs of keypoints between the current frame & the previous one. The code for this function is pretty long, but should be similar to [`cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/da1/classcv_1_1BFMatcher.html#ac6418c6f87e0e12a88979ea57980c020)
- Once we have the matched pairs of keypoints, we can use them to find the affine transform with this function :

  ```
  previousKpts = previousKpts[:5]  # select 4 best matches
  currentKpts = currentKpts[:5]

  # build A matrix of shape [2 * Nb of keypoints, 4]
  A = np.ndarray(((2 * len(previousKpts), 4)))

  for idx, keypoint in enumerate(previousKpts):
      # Keypoint.pt = (x-coord, y-coord)
      A[2 * idx, :] = [keypoint.pt[0], -keypoint.pt[1], 1, 0]
      A[2 * idx + 1, :] = [keypoint.pt[1], keypoint.pt[0], 0, 1]

  # build b matrix of shape [2 * Nb of keypoints, 1]
  b = np.ndarray((2 * len(previousKpts), 1))

  for idx, keypoint in enumerate(currentKpts):
      b[2 * idx, :] = keypoint.pt[0]
      b[2 * idx + 1, :] = keypoint.pt[1]

  # convert the numpy.ndarrays to matrix :
  A = np.matrix(A)
  b = np.matrix(b)

  # solution of the form x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]' = ((A' * A)^-1) * A' * b
  x = np.linalg.inv(A.T * A) * A.T * b

  theta = math.atan2(x[1, 0], x[0, 0])  # outputs rotation angle in [-pi, pi]
  alpha = math.sqrt(x[0, 0] ** 2 + x[1, 0] ** 2)  # scaling parameter
  bx = x[2, 0]  # translation along x-axis
  by = x[3, 0]  # translation along y-axis


  return theta, alpha, bx, by
  ```
- We then just have to apply the same affine transform to the corner points of the bounding rectangle :

  ```
  # define the 4 bounding points using xA, yA
  xB = xA + w
  yB = yA + h
  rect_pts = np.array([[[xA, yA]], [[xB, yA]], [[xA, yB]], [[xB, yB]]], dtype=np.float32)

  # warp the affine transform into a full perspective transform
  affine_warp = np.array([[alpha*np.cos(theta), -alpha*np.sin(theta), tx],
                          [alpha*np.sin(theta), alpha*np.cos(theta), ty],
                          [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

  # apply affine transform
  rect_pts = cv2.perspectiveTransform(rect_pts, affine_warp)
  xA = rect_pts[0, 0, 0]
  yA = rect_pts[0, 0, 1]
  xB = rect_pts[3, 0, 0]
  yB = rect_pts[3, 0, 1]

  return xA, yA, xB, yB
  ```
- Save the updated rectangle coordinates `(xA, yA, xB, yB)`, all current keypoints & descriptors, and iterate over the next frame : select `image[yA: yB, xA: xA]` using `(xA, yA, xB, yB)` we previously saved, get SURF keypoints etc.

Comment: You should take this question to cross validated, because you aren't asking about the programming language.

Instead, you're asking a math question with a reference to computer science.

Comment: cv2.perspectiveTransform function on all 4 bounding box points

Comment: Small comment: `some_list[:5]` returns the first *five* elements, with indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...not the first four.

Answer (score 1):

As Micka suggested, [`cv2.perspectiveTransform()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform) is an easy way to accomplish this. You'll just need to turn your affine warp into a full perspective transform (homography) by adding a third row at the bottom with the values `[0, 0, 1]`. For example, let's put a box with `w, h = 100, 200` at the point `(10, 20)` and then use an affine transformation to shift the points so that the box is moved to `(0, 0)` (i.e. shift 10 pixels to the left and 20 pixels up):

```
>>> xA, yA, w, h = (10, 20, 100, 200)
>>> xB, yB = xA + w, yA + h
>>> rect_pts = np.array([[[xA, yA]], [[xB, yA]], [[xA, yB]], [[xB, yB]]], dtype=np.float32)
>>> affine_warp = np.array([[1, 0, -10], [0, 1, -20], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
>>> cv2.perspectiveTransform(rect_pts, affine_warp)
array([[[   0.,    0.]],

       [[ 100.,    0.]],

       [[   0.,  200.]],

       [[ 100.,  200.]]], dtype=float32)
```

So that works perfectly as expected. You could also just simply transform the points yourself with matrix multiplication:

```
>>> rect_pts.dot(affine_warp[:, :2]) + affine_warp[:, 2]
array([[[   0.,    0.]],

       [[ 100.,    0.]],

       [[   0.,  200.]],

       [[ 100.,  200.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for this, that’s better. I would guess we need all 4 corner points to properly apply an affine transform. A quick test with `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform` indicates that an affine transform fits better the pedestrian motion.
Yet, the bounding rectangle is expanding after some frames, and it loses track of the pedestrian : [see here](https://ibb.co/bAxoc6) 
I am not sure where this comes from, as the size of the pedestrian is reducing with the depth of field. Are we missing a constraint on the bounding rectangle scaling ? Or is due to the rotation ?

Comment: @LucDupont The squash is indeed surprising, is it possible that you're getting the points out of order along the way? I'm not sure how you're defining the ROI, can you edit your original question with some of your code?

Comment: @AlexanderDupont The question has been edited with more code & context. I don't think the squash is coming from the ROI, but is more intrinsically linked to the affine transform. Perhaps adding another constraint would help?

Comment: @LucDupont you're finding an affine transformation for something that is not described by an affine transformation. Affine transformations (and homographies for that matter) only describe planar transformations. You are tracking a moving person...if their arm swings yet the descriptor between frames happens to be a better match than the other descriptors, then your top matches will include the arm swing in the affine transformation and it assumes the whole body has moved that way. If you're doing tracking I'd suggest looking into the background subtractor in OpenCV. Or optical flow.